# How to extract millisecond from date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, timestamp

i have full date(with time). 
But i want only millisecond from date.

please tell me one line solution

for example: `date= 2016/03/16 10:45:04.252` 
i want this answer= `252`

i try to use this query.

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(millisecond, -datepart('2016/03/16 10:45:04.252', millisecond),
     '2016/03/16 10:45:04.252') FROM DUAL;
```

but i'm not success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> i have full date (with time)

This can only be done using a `timestamp`. Although Oracle's `date` does contain a time, it only stores seconds, not milliseconds.

---

To get the fractional seconds from a **timestamp** use `to_char()` and convert that to a number:

```
select to_number(to_char(timestamp '2016-03-16 10:45:04.252', 'FF3'))
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks you for efforts.i got my answer

Comment: This is the cleanest answer.

Comment: What about `EXTRACT( timestamp_value, MILLISECOND )` ? (**EDIT**: Ah, that's only in "Oracle Big Data", not Oracle Database, even in version 21c, that's crazy...)

Comment: I noticed that this works in Oracle 11g: `SELECT ( timestamp_value - CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) ) ) AS ms FROM tableName` however the type of `ms` is still `timestamp(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
TRUNC((L.OUT_TIME-L.IN_TIME)*24)           ||':'||
TRUNC((L.OUT_TIME-L.IN_TIME)*24*60)        ||':'||
ROUND(CASE WHEN ((L.OUT_TIME-L.IN_TIME)*24*60*60)>60 THEN ((L.OUT_TIME-L.IN_TIME)*24*60*60)-60 ELSE ((L.OUT_TIME-L.IN_TIME)*24*60*60) END ,5) Elapsed
FROM XYZ_TABLE
```

Comment: code only answers, while being correct, are not really useful to understand the solution. Please consider adding some text explaining what you have done and what the code means

Answer (score 0):

The millisecond of the day:

```sql
  select to_number(to_char(tms_now, 'sssss') || to_char(tms_now, 'ff3')) day_millisecond
    from (select systimestamp as tms_now from dual);
```

The microsecond of the day:

```sql
  select to_number(to_char(tms_now, 'sssss') || to_char(tms_now, 'ff')) day_microsecond
    from (select systimestamp as tms_now from dual);
```